# Pegar valor de um atributo na td

Tags: jquery

Eu tenho uma tabela dinâmica onde existe 9 colunas
Em uma das últimas colunas existe um botão de ***reprovação***, e quando eu clicar nele, queria pegar o ***nome*** que está dentro de uma **td** na mesma **tr** dinamicamente.

***SCRIPT***

```
    $(document).on("click", ".btn-danger", function(){
        var nomePessoa = $(this).parent().parent().find("td").attr("nomePessoa");
        alert(nomePessoa);
    });
```

***TABELA***
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acho que usar `.closest('tr')` é mais seguro do que `.parent().parent()` n vezes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Para utilizar um atributo "personalizado" você deve utilizar o `data-`, montei um exemplo para você entender melhor.

***HTML***

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td data-nome="Lorem Ipsum">Nome attr data-</td>
        <td><button class="btn-danger">Recuperar nome</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Note que criei o atributo `data-nome` será onde iremos armazenar o nome para capturar depois com o JQuery (código abaixo).

***JQuery***

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-danger', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault;
        var nome = $(this).closest('tr').find('td[data-nome]').data('nome');
        alert(nome);
    });
});
```

***[Créditos ao Sergio (otimização do código)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/129/sergio)***

Você pode ver o exemplo funcionando nesta **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/4ZEx2/)**

Comment: Bem útil esta informação.

Comment: Diego, já que a sua resposta foi a aceite, se concordar mude/adicione `.closest('tr')` em vez de `.parent().parent()`. Assim evita uma chain de `.parent()` _n vezes_ e a resposta fica melhor a meu ver. Outro problema que tem na sua resposta/exemplo é que ele não funciona com a tabela que o Tafarel mostrou. Se adicionar a primeira coluna que ele mostra o seu código não funciona (http://jsfiddle.net/4ZEx2/1/). Mas se usar `.find('td[data-nome]')` ai já vai funcionar bem (http://jsfiddle.net/4ZEx2/2/). Aí a minha sugestão seria assim: http://jsfiddle.net/4ZEx2/3/

Comment: @Sergio muito obrigado pelo toque, código alterado.

Answer (score 3):

Consegui resolver colocando ao invés de um atributo, uma classe chamada "nome" no `td` com a informação de pessoa. O código ficou da seguinte forma:

```
    $(document).on("click", ".btn-danger", function(){
        var nomePessoa = $(this).parent().parent().find(".nome").text();
        alert(nomePessoa);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Sugiro usar o `.closest('tr')` para subir no DOM até ao `<tr>` e depois usar o `.find('td[nomePessoa])` para encontrar somente `td`com um atributo "nomePessoa".

Assim:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-danger", function () {
    var nomePessoa = $(this).closest('tr').find('td[nomePessoa]').attr('nomePessoa');
    alert(nomePessoa);
});
```

Deixo também um conselho, que é uma norma adotada na comunidade, use campos `data-`. Assim o seu código HTML seria `<td data-nomePessoa="Antonio" ... etc` e no javascript/jQuery `.data('nomePessoa')`em vez de `.attr('nomePessoa')`

Answer (score 0):

Gostei da resposta do Diego Vieira(+1) pois não conhecia esse atributo data-qualquercoisa que pode ser criado.

No entanto, fui por um caminho diferente, pois vi que o nome já se encontrava escrito dentro da td e fui tentar pegá-lo com `innerHTML`. Não consegui com o código utilizado pois trata-se de um objeto JQuery e não é assim com `.innerHTML` que funciona a manipulação com Jquery. O Jquery cria um encapsulamento para conteúdo que é diferente de usar `elemento = document.getElementById("iddoelmento");`.

Daí me surgiu uma curiosidade: Como poderia fazer para pegar os nomes das propriedades e métodos de objetos de qualquer natureza, seja jquery ou não? Descobri a existência do `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(nomedoobjeto)` ao pesquisar no Stack Overflow em inglês.

No teste em questão o objeto localizado com Jquery tinha as seguintes propriedades:
 0,1,length,prevObject,context,selector

Comecei testando o 0 e era o elemento que precisava. `tdobj[0].innerHTML` retorna o conteúdo da célula localizada.

Gostaria de compartilhar a experiência, segue o código executável abaixo.

```js
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-danger', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault;
        //tdobj = $(this).parent().parent().find('td');
        tdobj = $(this).closest('tr').find('td');

        // lalala = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(tdobj);
     // alert(lalala);
        //  0,1,length,prevObject,context,selector


        alert("[0]: "             + tdobj[0]);
        alert("[0].innerHTML:\n"  + tdobj[0].innerHTML);

        alert("[1]: "             + tdobj[1]);
        alert("[1].innerHTML:\n"  + tdobj[1].innerHTML);

        alert("length: "     + tdobj["length"]);

        alert("prevObject: " + tdobj["prevObject"]);

        alert("context: "    + tdobj["context"]);

        alert("selector: "   + tdobj["selector"]);

  
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Teste Nome do Cara</td>
        <td><button class="btn-danger">Recuperar nome</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Referência: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257993/how-to-display-all-methods-of-an-object-in-javascript?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score -1):

Eu consegui retornar o resultado de uma forma mais simples.

determina um id dentro de cada  e utiliza a função .text().

var tamanhopage = $("#tamanhopage").text();

Valor.

Funcionou pra mim aqui! Boa Sorte.

Comment: Agradecemos sua vontade de compartilhar conhecimento, mas isso não responde à pergunta. Sendo um usuário novo, recomendo que comece fazendo o [tour] para conhecer melhor o sistema. Em respostas futuras, tente explicar melhor o desenvolvimento, explicando o que cada função faz e, de preferência, citando a fonte das mesmas na documentação.